# Why does Buster not join in the family chicken dance?

Tags: analysis, arrested-development

Throughout the series Arrested Development, the various adult members of Michael's family all perform variations of the chicken dance to annoy Michael. At one point in Season 3, Michael himself does a chicken impression while on the phone to Lindsay (only the sound effects, not a dance though).

Why does Buster not have his own chicken dance? Is it because GOB has been shown to intimidate him with it in the past (which enrages Buster when they are working on the construction site in Season 1)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know if there's a definitive reason why Buster doesn't do a chicken dance over the course of the show, but there are a few possibilities that could make sense depending on how much you want to read between the lines. Your thought concerning GOB using his dance to intimidate Buster is certainly something to consider. It's probably also important to note that Buster's response in that episode was that "chickens don't clap," typical of Buster's approach to coping with many Bluthian activities. This very literal perception of GOB's dance reminds us how Buster sees the world, eschewing things that don't generally make any sense to him.

I also wonder if it might not be fruitful to think about the constant doubt surrounding Buster's lineage -- that is, as yet another sign that he's not full Bluth (of course, Tobias isn't a Bluth, either, but him performing his own Chicken Dance is perfectly consistent with his playing parts to achieve his desire to be fully accepted of the groups he associates with). Or along the same lines, perhaps the lack of the Chicken Dance is more a demonstration of the lack of George's presence in Buster's life as a father figure.

Or maybe Buster is just too afraid (too chicken ... ha ha) to do it himself. Of course, this is all just speculation, and maybe Buster will bust out his own dance in the first episode of the new season.

One interesting thing is that at last year's reunion, when Portia de Rossi and Will Arnett started doing their dances at the request of an audience member, Tony Hale started to clap along (http://youtu.be/gTsu-ks9Gb8) -- maybe chickens do clap after all?

Comment: Interesting points - though seeing as Lindsay is not a Bluth, I'm more inclined to go with your point on Buster not seeing George as a father figure and therefore not emulating him in that regard (whereas Lindsay and Tobias do regard him in that way). I must ask though, when does Tobias do a chicken dance? I know he was watching from the kitchen when George, Lucille and Lindsay chicken danced for Michael in the apartment (and GOB was too late to join in). Either way, I'm hoping to see Buster break out a chicken dance in the new season.

Comment: @Arabella *"new season"* - What the...? Really? That'd be amazing!

Comment: @Arabella He doesn't, but does make chicken-like noises when assisting Gob in his 'Free Bird/Free Chicken' illusion (*not* trick) in the episode "For British Eyes Only."

Comment: @Arabella That's right ... I wasn't thinking of that fact that Lindsay was adopted. I guess that means genetics aren't the determining factor at all, here.

Comment: @ChristianRau -- http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2012/08/23/arrested-development-spring-netflix_n_1824588.html

Comment: How is Buster not a full Bluth? Whether his father is George or Oscar, he's always as much of a Bluth. Also, you may have glossed over the fact Lucille isn't a genetic Bluth.